# Error in mysql update query insterting multiple entries into single column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I am getting an error on attempting to insert/update single field with multiple entries.

Here is database scheme:

```
id INT(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(64),
hobby VARCHAR(500)
```

HostServer Php version is 5

Here is what my form code is :-

```
<form method=post>
<label>name</label>
<input type=text name=name>
<label>hobby</label>
<select name="hobby[]"  multiple="multiple">
<option value=1>gardening
<option value=2>Music
<option value=3>Movies
<option value=4>Games
</select>
</form>
```

Now for processing the multiple values am using following php code :-

```
foreach($_POST['hobby'] as $key => $value){
  $_POST['hobby'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);}
  $hobby = $_POST['hobby'];
  $hobby = "('" . implode("'),('" , $hobby). "')";
  $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET name='".$name."',hobby='".$hobby."'");
```

But am getting the following error on output :-

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2'),('3')' on line....

I know this is the entries related to hobby field but am unable to find an way to 
correct it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you once dump your final query statement, then you will immediately see what causes that syntax error. Your quoting is wrong.

Comment: However you implement your code on a deprecated database driver which is insecure. This is clearly stated in the documentation. I suggest you take a look at the newer `mysqli` driver instead and learn about the advantages of "prepared statements" before investing more time into the current approach.

Comment: Problem is with your `implode()` with the unescaped parentheses and quotes. Try to fix it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to help your self

change this line

```
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET name='".$name."',hobby='".$hobby."'");
```

for debugging into

```
 $query = "UPDATE `users` SET name='".$name."',hobby='".$hobby."'";
 echo $query;
 die;
```

after this you can see that your query isn't valid. check out the error and fix your implode

Comment: This isn't an answer. It is a suggestion how to identify the problem and find the answer oneself. Thus this should have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The Database schema looks a little strange but the only reason this isn't working is you need to escape the single quotes that you want to be entered into the database. This is done with a preceding '\'

```
$hobby = "(\'" . implode("\'),(\'" , $hobby). "\')";
```

There are other issues to consider though, for one this statement will update every record in the database because you haven't specified a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

you also are not passing the content of the name field to to the SQL statement. you should chnage:

```
$name to $_POST['name']
```